# Flutter how to solve AndroidX incompatibility

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

When I install the geolocator package in my Flutter project, I get the error in the first picture. When I set the minSdkVerison value to 21, the error changes and I get the 2nd error. But I guess the 2nd error has nothing to do with the geolocator because if I uninstall the geolocator package, I get that error when the minSdkVersion is 21. I tried flutter clean and set multiDexEnabled to true but it didn't fix. How can I solve this problem?

[minsdk16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSgXH.png)

[minsdk21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYF5f.png)

app level build.gradle

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_biasansor"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex: 2.0.1'




}
```

project level build.gradle

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.properties

```
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using for Firestore?
Set SDK to 21 and leave multidex as it was, version 21 handles it. Use the latest versions of geolocator and Firestore, based on your null-safety status.

Comment: `cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  provider: ^5.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.11.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.0
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
  clippy_flutter: ^1.1.1
` i already using latest version of firestore but it still doesnt work i removed geolocator but 2nd error still occur

Comment: What error do you get? Just set it to minSDK 21, and return your multidex and other parameters as they were. You will not get an error if you keep the multiDex options default. The error int he picture of v21 sdk says can't find multidex2.0.1, meaning that it has probably been changed. Set multidex to false, and target SDK to 29, minSDK 21, see if it works

Comment: multiDex was true from the beginning i only changed minSDK value 16 to 21. And i got that error ` What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.multidex:multidex: 2.0.1.
   ....
`

Comment: if i change minsdk 21 to 16 and remove geolocator then my program running without error. But in minsdk 16 if i add geolocator package i get error in picture of minsdk16. When i change minsdk16 to 21 then i get error in picture minsdk21.

Comment: before all of these errors when i set minsdk to 21 i get this error.`[!] Flutter tried to create the file android\settings_aar.gradle, but failed.
To manually update settings.gradle , follow these steps:

    1. Copy settings.gradle as settings_aar.gradle
    2. Remove the following code from settings_aar.gradle:` 
This problem was solved when I did as flutter said. Could there be a relevance between these errors?

Comment: while minSDK is 21, is multidex false? and still same error"?

Comment: yes. i set multidex to false but it didnt work still same error